# Excel removes '+' as a first character of a string

Tags: javascript, excel, papaparse

I am exporting mobile nos from JSON to CSV using Papa Parse. Each mobile no has a country code which starts with `+` as the first character. The list is exported but when I open the CSV file in microsoft excel the `+` gets removed from the mobile no string.

```js
const profileListDownload = [];
let dataid = 1;

list.forEach(e => {
  const newRow = {};
  newRow["dataid"] = e.dataid;
  newRow["mobileno"] = e.mobileno;
  profileListDownload.push(newRow);
  dataid++;
});

const csv = Papa.unparse(JSON.stringify(profileListDownload));
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([csv]));
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute("download", "ProfileEdit.csv"); //or any other extension
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

But when I open the csv file using google sheets or notepad. The `+` character is present.

Comment: Excel is seeing the values as numbers. You need to **IMPORT** the csv into Excel so that you can tell Excel to treat the column as **Text**.  Alternatively, you can prepend the value with a single-quote, or you may be able to surround the value by double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an apostrophe before the plus sign like this: `'+` this way Excel passes over it and doesn't treat it like a value.

If all of the numbers have the + before them then you should be able to just prepend the apostrophe onto the number in your loop.

```
list.forEach(e => {
  const newRow = {};
  newRow["dataid"] = e.dataid;
  newRow["mobileno"] = "'" + e.mobileno;
  profileListDownload.push(newRow);
  dataid++;
});
```

Comment: Using the above method I get `'+<country-code><mobileno>`. The apostrophe sign also gets appended to the string.

Comment: So where the function was producing the data before it's now giving you the name of the variable in angle brackets? You could prepare the data prior to setting it as new row, I don't see country code in your example but try to prep a new variable that formats the string with the needed symbols before it inside the foreach `let prepped = "'" + yourcountrycodevar + e.mobileno` and then set `newRow["mobileno"] = prepped`