# How to paste phone numbers in excel correctly

Tags: excel, visual-studio-code, excel-2010

I'm working with data in excel and I want to paste some data from vscode (fetched from db) and paste it in excel to compare

data in vscode:

```
+19292090000;{CLOSING_SCHEDULER}
+19495380000;{LOAN_OFFICER_ASSISTANT}
+16468320000;{CLOSER,LOCK_DESK,POST_CLOSING_BULK_UPLOAD}
```

When I paste this data after selecting a column I get Error(screenshot attached)
[image]

I understand here the problem is with the data(probably the length of data or curly brackets)

Now I only try to paste only the phone data i.e.

```
+19292090000
+19495380000
+16468320000
```

We get =+ in the formulae bar and i'm expecting it to be only + (Without '=')

I want it to be shown like this
[image]

I don't have any experience with excel and want to fix this
So, that I can compare my data which is in different sheet

P.S: I'm using google sheets

[image]

Comment: Toss a single quote on the front of those values and you should be good. That essentially tells excel "This is text, don't treat like a formula or a number".

Comment: related (about programmatic uses, whereas this question is not): https://stackoverflow.com/q/62808080/11107541

Answer (score 1):

Just set the format of cells to Text would be ok:

Sorry I only have the traditional Chinese version, you can find the item by the end text of "(F)". Click on that will pop up the next pic shown ( click right button of your mouse will pop up this menu)

[image]

Select the Text item in that list box and click on OK button. Then you can try pasting again using right button of your mouse and clicking the plain text selection.

[image]
[image]